# Laravel Query Builder Eloquent

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel

How can i make this query in Laravel?

```
SELECT GS_CONTRATOS.*,GS_ACESSOS.* from GS_CONTRATOS
full outer join GS_ACESSOS on GS_ACESSOS.CONTRATO_ID=GS_CONTRATOS.ID
where EMPRESA_ID='1' and (WEBUSER='ec' or WEBUSER is null)
```

i got my one like this and gives me 0 results, i have tried to use 2 wheres with varius variables but is not working because i cant get both of wheres. i cant explain more than this bcs i dont even know how to make this query

She was suposed to give me all results in GS_ACESSO and all GS_CONTRATOS even if doesnt exist in one of them.

```
$contratos = Contrato::query()
->join('GS_ACESSOS','GS_ACESSOS.CONTRATO_ID','=','GS_CONTRATOS.ID','full outer')
->where('GS_ACESSOS.WEBUSER','=',$id)->orWhere('EMPRESA_ID','=',$emp)
->get(['GS_CONTRATOS.*','GS_ACESSOS.*']);
```

Comment: *its not working..* - Please include what exactly that means in your question so we don't have to spend time and effort studying the code just to figure out what problem you're encountering.

Comment: You don't need to start a query with `::query()`, it's redundant. Just do `Contrato::join(...)->where(...)`. I keep seeing this, and I have no idea why...

Comment: its bcs if someone that doesnt understand the code can look and kinda understand its a SQL query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to add parenthesis, you must use the where condition with a closure. There you go:

```
$contratos = Contrato::query()
    ->join('GS_ACESSOS','GS_ACESSOS.CONTRATO_ID','=','GS_CONTRATOS.ID','full outer')
    ->where('GS_ACESSOS.WEBUSER', $id)
    ->where(function ($q) use ($emp) {
        $q->where('WEBUSER', 'ec')
            ->orWhere('EMPRESA_ID', $emp);
    })
    ->get(['GS_CONTRATOS.*','GS_ACESSOS.*']);
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#logical-grouping